# Android - Downloaded image from url is broken

Tags: java, android

I'm using `URL` to download and save image in Android. but sometimes saved image is broken and half of them get blacked.
for example see this:
[image]

I use this code:

```
URL _url = new URL(url);
_url.openConnection().setReadTimeout(10000);
_url.openConnection().setConnectTimeout(10000);
InputStream is = _url.openStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath + fileName);
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
    os.write(b, 0, length);
}
is.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: Are there any exception stack traces? Although this code has some flaws, it seems that the problem could be somwhere else.

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Cichocki. Because this problem happened one in 200 test, I don't check stack trace. this code inside try/catch of a function, so problem not in somewhere else.

Comment: please reproduce the error and post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Krzysztof Cichocki ,you are right. I think this problem happening because i calling save function in multi thread at the same time!